# Django timeseries format and highcharts

Tags: django, python-3.x, highcharts, time-series

I'm trying to implement a timeseries in highcharts using Django 2.x

```
{% for date in timeseries.all %}
{{ date }}
{% if not forloop.last %},
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This gives the following as output:

```
{'flotation_date': datetime.datetime(2002, 2, 2, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)} , 
{'flotation_date': datetime.datetime(2002, 2, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)} , 
{'flotation_date': datetime.datetime(2002, 2, 3, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)} , 
{'flotation_date': datetime.datetime(2002, 2, 4, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}
```

Highcharts is expecting:

```
  1167609600000,
  0.7537
  ],
  [
  1167696000000,
  0.7537
  ],
  [
  1167782400000,
  0.7559
  ],
  [
  1167868800000,
  0.7631
  ],
```

So the obvious question, how to transform the dictionary into the expected array?

n.b. at this point the time has been omitted, it will be added later.

In my views the data is returned like so, I anticipate this is where the formatting will take place.

```
timeseries = Flotation.objects.values('flotation_date')
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this ?

Comment: no, still on my to do list!

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple way to do this. If your date is a datetime object, do the following.

```
yourdate.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp() * 1000
```

This will give you the timestamp. **Please note I am creating chart objects in my django views not in templates**. But you can write a tag to use in your templates to return the date in EPOCH seconds.